# Is there an upate to Apple Hardware Test? It locks up while testing

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Apple Hardware Test 3.3.1 -3A152 comes with my MacBook Pro 17", 2008 on the included OSX 10.6.3 DVD/CD. When I use it on my not-booting Mac, AHT locks up and never finishes tests and therefore there is no result list.

Wished AHT would list tested hardware and show results as it goes - step-by-step. Instead of listing results at the very end, when AHT might have locked up - with no results at all...

Answer (score 1):

There have been many updates…
unfortunately your machine is too old to use them.

It can only use a DVD-based version, not the latest internet-based test.

There is a blog post about how to boot to AHT from a downloaded AHT file, loaded to a USB key, but you will need a working Mac to be able to construct it.

From : [Riven by Five - Download and run Apple Hardware Test (AHT) from a USB drive.](http://rivenbyfive.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/download-and-run-apple-hardware-test.html)

*My additions in italics*

> 1) Download the AHT for your computer (see downloads below for specific models).
>
> 1b) My copy had me convert the downloaded .dmg from some “old” type using Disk Utility. (Just open the .dmg in Disk Utility and “Convert” to a new target, then mount the target.)
>
> 2) Mount and completely wipe a USB stick.
>   *Format it GUID/Mac OS Extended (Journaled)*
>   *Most USB sticks will be MBR/FAT by default, so just formatting to Mac OS without changing the underlying structure to GUID will not work*
>
> 3) From the AHT image, copy /System to the root folder of your USB stick:
>   *by typing the following in Terminal [Applications/Utilities]*
>
> `cd /Volumes/USB_STICK/ && cp -r ~/AHT_ARCHIVE/System`
>
> 4) Now, from the USB drive, copy the /System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics/diags.efi to the root directory:
>
> `cd /Volumes/USB_STICK/ && cp ./System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics/diags.efi`
>
> 5) Shutdown all applications, *except Terminal.*
>
> *6) the original 6) below assumes you are booting to the same machine you are trying to test*
>   *to attempt to use this on a different machine omit the `&& sudo reboot` & instead eject the USB after that command, then move to your target machine*
>
> 6) “bless” the USB drive in mount-mode, with the EFI file, and immediately reboot:
>
> `cd /Volumes/USB_STICK/ && sudo bless --mount /Volumes/USB_STICK --setBoot --file diags.efi && sudo reboot`
>
> *7) Cold boot your target machine*
>    You should now be booting into AHT -- don’t hold down any keys.
>
> 8) Run the tests, and yank the USB key after AHT reboots you.
>
> You can download the AHT package for your computer using this URL:
>
> `http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/018-[MODEL NUMBER]-A.dmg`
>
> where [MODEL NUMBER] is the four-number ID below:
>
> 3282 for Mac-F4208AC8, Mac-F42289C8 Xserve1,1 and Xserve2,1
>   3259 for Mac-F42C8CC8 MacBookAir1,1
>   3273 for Mac-F42C88C8 MacPro3,1
>   3254 for F4238CC8, F42386C8, F4218EC8, F4208EAA, F4208DC8, F4208DA9, F4238BC8, F42388C8 and F22788C8 inclusively.
>
> or more specifically:
>   3085 for Mac-F22788C8 MacBook3,1
>   2886 for Mac-F4208EAA Macmini2,1
>   2845 for Mac-F42386C8 iMac7,1
>   2833 for Mac-F42388C8 MacBookPro3,1
>   2770 for Mac-F4238BC8 MacBookPro3,1
>   2769 for Mac-F4208DC8 MacPro1,1
>   2667 for Mac-F4208DA9 MacPro2,1
>   2766 for Mac-F4208CAA MacBook2,1
>   2592 for Mac-F42189C8 MacBookPro2,1
>   2591 for Mac-F42187C8 MacBookPro2,2
>   2590 for Mac-F4208CA9 MacBook2,1
>   2579 for Mac-F4218FC8 iMac6,1
>   2535 for Mac-F4218EC8 iMac5,2
>   2534 for Mac-F4228EC8 iMac5,1
>   2533 for Mac-F42786A9 iMac5,1
>   And these are there, but too old to identify: 2418, 2405, 2398, 2393, 2392, 2342, 2216, 2215, 2158, 2120, 2079, 2056, 1880, 1879, 1680 and 1594.